# Use widget as button - android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, button, widget

I have a widget, and I would like to open a new window, when the user clicks on the widget.
Can someone please tell me how to do this, and can you please give me some code?
I'm currently learning how to make android apps in Eclipse using java.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Search properly, you will get many tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can make any view clickable by adding

```
android:clickable="true"
```

to the xml or by calling

```
view.setClickable(true);
```

in java.
See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Then you can assign an [on click listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) to do any actions you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Class which extends `AppWidgetProvider` .you can see [basic example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html) for ceating simple widget.So you can detect click event of your widget in class which extends AppWidgetProvider. Here, MyWidgetProvider is an Service which will run in Background .

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                int[] appWidgetIds) {

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetview);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetlayout1, buildButtonPendingIntent(context));
        pushWidgetUpdate(context, remoteViews);
        }

    public static PendingIntent buildButtonPendingIntent(Context context) {

      Log.d("MyWidgetProvider", "click");
     Intent intent = new Intent(context,secondactivity.class);// Add secondactivity to Manifest
     context.startActivity(intent);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }
```

I have seen your [link](http://androidthings.blogspot.in/2013/03/jump-into-android-create-battery-level.html#.UkZkXtcakom) which you are using.. You can put above code in your `LovelyBatteryWidget` Class.

**EDIT**

```
public static void pushWidgetUpdate(Context context, RemoteViews remoteViews) {
        ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        manager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, remoteViews);     
    }
```

Check [this](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/android-complete-widget-tutorial-including-source-code/) Tutorial for your reference.

Comment: I have 1 errors: pushWidgetUpdate(context, remoteViews); //Can't find the method

Comment: If I create a new pushWidgetUpdate() method, what should I place inside the method?

Comment: Should I place the whole code, with the class declaration, inside the LovelyBatteryWidget Class? What should I place inside the pushWidgetUpdate Method, that I have to create, so I don't get the can't find method error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was looking at the tutorial and they use a a widget button, and I also looked at the new boston tutorial and they also use a button, so my question is: How can I convert the widget to a button, so I can use the listener on that button? Please look at the code on the website I'm using. This is the line where I need to use this button:remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, buildButtonPendingIntent(context)); //Instead of thewidget_button this code is from the tutorial link you gave me

Comment: Is there a way I could add the drawable that is used as a widget to a button?

Comment: remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, buildButtonPendingIntent(context)); ...you can add your main layout id at R.id.widget_button..like R.id.layout1..now u can use as it is.

Answer (score -1):

Make  another activity for new window in my code  it  is  ***seconhdActivity***

In onclickevent of your widget use the Intent That i use in my code

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(mIntent);
```

==========================================================================

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
Button btnButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(mIntent);

        }
    });

}
```

}